# How to detect any keyboard input anywhere on a page

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I have this start page that runs on my home server, and the start page is my homepage, the page that shows up when I make a new tab etc. and it has a list of all my web apps and bookmarks.

I'd like it so when the page loads, If I want to do a google search then I can just start typing and this overlay pops up with a search bar for me to search google with.

I have seen how people would use the `onkeypressed()` function to run code when something is typed **in a input field** but I want to run this piece of code (which will be the code that shows the overlay with the search bar) if the user starts typing anywhere on the page (when the user isn't in a input field)

e.g. The page loads and straight away the user starts typing, I want to instantly show an overlay with a search box and allow the user to type in that search box.

Can this be done, and if so, how? Is there a function for it?

Comment: You haven't offered us any code snippets, so I will only give suggestions for you to have a starting point.

To read what the user types 'globally', use: docoument.addEventListener ('keydown', event => {// code here})

Comment: @AksJacoves how can I give code snippets when I haven't got any code for this specific question yet?

Comment: And from what I understand you wanted a particular input to be focused when the user writes something, for that use the focus () method

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hope this help you!

```
 <html>
    <body>

    <p id="demo"></p>

    <script>

    document.addEventListener("keypress", function(event){
        var x = event.which || event.keyCode;
      document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "The Unicode value is: " + x;
    });

    </script>

    </body>
</html>
```